# cross merge/cartesian product in dask

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dask, cartesian-product

how can I perform the equivalent of this cross merge in dask?

```
merged_df = pd.merge(df, df, how='cross', suffixes=('', '_y'))
```

To provide an example, say I have this dataframe, say dataframe A:

```
#Niusup Niucust
#1        a
#1        b 
#1        c
#2        d
#2        e
```

and want to obtain this one:

```
#Niusup Niucust_x Niucust_y
#1        a       a
#1        a       b
#1        a       c
#1        b       a 
#1        b       b
#1        b       c
#1        c       a 
#1        c       b
#1        c       c
#2        d       d 
#2        d       e
#2        e       d
#2        e       e
```

I need Dask because dataframe A contains 5000000 observations and so I expect the cartesian product to contain a lot of observations.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'#Niusup': {0: '#1', 1: '#1', 2: '#1', 3: '#2', 4: '#2'},
 'Niucust': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Code**

```
g = df.groupby('#Niusup')
dfs = [g.get_group(x) for x in g.groups]
pd.concat([df_i.merge(df_i.drop('#Niusup', axis=1), how='cross',suffixes=('', '_y')) for df_i in dfs])
```

output:

```
    #Niusup Niucust Niucust_y
0   #1      a       a
1   #1      a       b
2   #1      a       c
3   #1      b       a
4   #1      b       b
5   #1      b       c
6   #1      c       a
7   #1      c       b
8   #1      c       c
0   #2      d       d
1   #2      d       e
2   #2      e       d
3   #2      e       e
```

Comment: this actually gives me a key error: KeyError: 1002000415

Comment: @Lusian Isn't there something wrong with the example code? I updated the answer by making your example into code.

Comment: Maybe I transformed the columns into categories before. I will check again

Comment: @Lusian I've slightly modified the similar code.

Comment: #Panda Kim thanks it works. So this better the performance and works also on very large data right?

Comment: @Lusian right. slightly better